# Module can import through anaconda prompt, but not through python.exe

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I am fairly new to python and have found something annoying but interesting.

My python installation was done via anaconda and I have installed the module prtools using pip.
Then I found that the module only imports when I use Spyder and not when using VSCode. So I went to investigate and hit a wall. I have found that when I open anaconda prompt and type `python` it opens the python interpreter and I can import the prtools module without problems. Then I used `where python` to find its location, which gave me two locations:

"E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"

and

"C:\Users\Joris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"

Clicking on the second one only opens the windows store. And clicking the first one opens a python console (I believe its called). Now when I type `import prtools` It gives an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prtools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from prtools.dataset import *
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prtools\dataset.py", line 10, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Joris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2356, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "C:\Users\Joris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Joris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
  File "C:\Users\Joris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 45, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anybody have an idea where this problem might come from?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple python interpreters installed. From your terminal you are talking to a different python interpreter than when you are executing your project through VSC which uses a different python interpreter.

In your terminal directly execute python with `"E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"` and `"C:\Users\Joris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"`

You can substitute `python` with those paths.

Try to find differences with `python -V`, `python -m site`.
The latter call lists the root folders for your installed python modules. In one of those folders you will find the python files for `prtools`.

So the problem is that you have multiple python installation and in one of them `prtools` was installed.

It is recommended to work with a single python version and to use `venv` (virtual environments).